# SpreadSheetGear cannot access series 3d Format

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, spreadsheetgear

I can access the ISeries "fill" and "line" and then under those classes there is "format" which allows you to create gradients.

However, in Excel itself the series format has "3D effect" section where you can set Shape Outline, Shape Preset to create a cool 3D effect on a bar graph.

I want to be able to set Preset 2 but there is no "3dEffect" or "effect" member for ISeries.

How do I modify the 3D effects of a bar graph series?

In excel you can do this by clicking "format" then "Shape Effects" then "presets".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SpreadsheetGear **cannot** do 3D shapes and effects yet according to spreadsheetgear support.